# Transfer an archive through NetworkStream

Tags: c#, stream, archive

I want to copy a directory tree through a TCP connection. The source side should start somewhere in the filesystem to gather all files recursively and send them to the sink side through a NetworkStream. This looks somehow as I could create a ZIP file at source side and send it to the client. But there are some requirements:

- There shouldn't be created any temporary files
- There shouldn't be created any files in memory
- The data should be send in-band.

The first two requirements could be fulfilled by sending a ZIP archive through the NetworkStream.
The temporary files should be avoided due to access right issues. The directory tree can contain huge amount of data what can cause out-of-memory issues.
The third requirement is a bit more complicated. There should be established only one TCP connection between source and sink.

The protocol uses the same connection before the data transmission for exchange of meta information like the directory name and after the data transmission to at least acknowledge the successfull transfer and that the data has been written to the file system.

I already tried SharpZipLib. But this reads always chunks of 4 KByte when reading a stream. It needs an end of stream to identify the end of the ZIP archive. This is inappropriate since the archive should be in-band.

The DotNetZip library documentation mentions that it needs a seekable stream, what is not available for a NetworkStream.

How can such directory structures be transferred?

**Edit** clarified that the file data must be embedded in the same TCP stream.

Comment: Have you tried `tar` for Windows, just starting it as a subprocess? It does exactly what you want and is routinely used to convert a dir-tree into a stream. Additionally it does both directions. You can pipe it through an external compressor or compress the stream inside C#. I also think that not reinventing the wheel is a good thing.

Comment: @EugenRieck Spawning a new process for each connection is a bit expensive. (Further I would get a 512 byte block for each file in the directory tree.)

Comment: Yes, there is the cost of spawning a process. But it is definitly tiny compared to the cost of traversing a directory tree, processing every single file, compressing the output and finally sendig it over a network. The 512 byte block size is a no-brainer after compression.

Comment: How is the cost reduced when the traversing is delegated to another process like tar?

Comment: What I mean is: The cost of traversing is (tens? hundreds? of) thousands of times higher than the cost of the external process, so spawning an external process doesn't really make a difference - in return you get a battle-proven and turn-key ready solution. Having a stream format that is easily compatible with the Unixes might also be a good point (a corresponding Unix app is a 2-line shellscript). Just my 2 cents.

Comment: From what I've seen DotNetZip does not require seekable stream. Also, what exactly does "inbound" mean?

Comment: "inbound" is a typo. I mean in-band and edited the question. Inband is to embed the data to be transferred in the existing stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right that DotNetZip doesn't seem to support non-seekable streams directly. But the only reason why it requires that is because it needs to know the `Position`, which non-seekable streams don't support.

To fix that, just wrap the `NetworkStream` in a `CountingStream`, provided as a part of DotNetZip. If you do that, you should be able to use `ZipOutputStream` just fine.

As an alternative, if you don't need compression, you could create your own tar-like protocol.

Something like

- 4 bytes for the length of the file name, including path (M)
- 8 bytes for the length of the file (N)
- M bytes for the file name (incl. path), encoded using UTF-8
- N bytes for the contents of the file itself

fore each file.